# Autocomplete Combobox

Tags: javascript, html, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using HTML, JavaScript, ASP .NET MVC3, and JSON for the autocomplete.

I have a text box where I implemented autocomplete. But I want to change the text box to a combobox. Is there some kind of tag I can use to easily change it to a combobox? If there is, what are some properties of the tag? Such as disallowing custom text to be searched so that only the suggested inputs from autocomplete can be submitted. If not how can I implement this kind of combobox. This what the code I have now looks like.

HTML:

```
<div id = "inputTable">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="labelText">Text1</span></td> 
        <td><input id="text1" type="text" placeholder="Enter Text1" data-text1autocomplete="@Url.Action("searchText1", "Scan")"/> </td> 
        <td style="width: 200px; text-align: left; margin-left: 5px"><button class="medium awesome blue" id="sendText1Button">Send Text1</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <span class="labelText">Text2</span> </td> 
        <td><input id="text2" type="text" placeholder="Enter Text2" data-text2autocomplete="@Url.Action("searchText2", "Scan")"/> </td>   
        <td style="width: 200px; text-align: left; margin-left: 5px"> <button class="medium awesome blue" id="sendText2Button">Send Text2</button> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(':input[data-text1autocomplete]').each(function () {
        $(this).autocomplete({ source: $(this).attr("data-text1autocomplete") });
    });

    $(':input[data-text2autocomplete]').each(function () {
        $(this).autocomplete({ source: $(this).attr("data-text2autocomplete") });
    });

    $('#sendText1Button').click(function () {
        var text1 = $("#text1").val();
        $('#loadingUsageInfo').css({ 'visibility': 'visible' });
        if (text1 == "" || text1 == 'Enter Text1') {
            alert('Enter Text1 First');
            return;
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ShowTable1", "Scan")',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({ inputText1: text1 }),
            traditional: true,
            success: function (result) {
                $('#hostusageinfo').html(result);
            }
        });
        $('#text1').val("");
        $('#text2').val("");
    });


    $('#sendText2Button').click(function () {
        var text2 = $("#text2").val();
        $('#loadingUsageInfo').css({ 'visibility': 'visible' });
        if (text2 == "" || text2 == 'Enter Text2') {
            alert('Enter Text2 First');
            return;
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ShowTable2", "Scan")',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({ inputText2: text2 }),
            traditional: true,
            success: function (result) {
                $('#hostusageinfo').html(result);
            }
        });
        $('#text1').val("");
        $('#text2').val("");
    });

    $('#text1, #text2').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            var text1 = $("#text1").val();
            var text2 = $("#text2").val();
            if ((text1 == "" || text1 == 'Enter Text1') && (text2 == "" || text2 == 'Enter Text2')) {
                alert('Enter Text First');
                return;
            }
            else if (text1 == "" || text1 == 'Enter Text1')
                $('#sendText2Button').trigger('click');
            else if (text2 == "" || text2 == 'Enter Text2')
                $('#sendText1Button').trigger('click');
        }
    });

});
```

Thanks to anyone that can help!

Comment: "If there is, what are some properties of the tag? Such as disallowing custom text to be searched so that only the suggested inputs from autocomplete can be submitted" Are you sure you don't just need a select list?

Comment: A select list doesn't allow the user to type in input. And I need them to be able to do that because there are so many options. Allowing them to begin typing then using the autocomplete to cut down the list is necessary.